# Android - Changing the contentview of the activity of Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, qr-code, zxing

I am creating a simple QR scanning app using Navigation drawer to go throw different fragments, for the QR scanning part I am using the ZXing Scanner library.

In one of the fragments, there is a button called "scan", When clicked the following code run

```
mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
setContentView(mScannerView); // HERE IS THE begining OF THE PROBLEM
mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
mScannerView.startCamera();
```

now in the `handleResult` method i should write the following code to close the camera.

```
mScannerView.stopCamera();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // THE PROBLEM OCCUERS HERE
```

When I run this code I get `Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment`

Any Idea how to solve this ?

Code :

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer
    .FragmentDrawerListener, ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id
            .drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    displayView(0);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new QRScanerFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_logout);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

public void scan(View view) {
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Log.e("QR result", result.getText());
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

}

as For the XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.bassiouny.androidqrtask.fragments.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: I would probably avoid calling `setContentView()` multiple times, as this will redraw the entirety of the view. Why not call the camera in a separate fragment, or if you are drawing the entire screen again, why not just start a new activity (for result)? Anyway, as far as the actual issue goes, show some code. What is in your XML file, and what does the fragment class look like that it is trying to inflate?

Comment: off course you will get error with setContentView() ,you can not do it this way you have either to start a new activity or as @Bryan  said a fragment

Comment: @Bryan , I added the code, I am trying to find a way that will allow me to use both the library of the QR scanner and the navigation drawer, that why I am not calling the camera as I need to do this throw the library.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) shows that `ZXingScannerView` is a descendant of the `View` class. Therefore you should be able to create a layout like this:

```
<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scanner"/>
```

Then you can create a `ScannerFragment` that uses this layout as its view:

```
@Override
public view onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scanner, container, false);
    mScannerView = (ZXingScannerView) view.findViewById(R.id.scanner);

    return view;
}
```

Then, instead of calling `setContentView` again in your `Activity`, you can replace the fragment with the `ScannerFragment`, just as you are with your other fragments:

```
Fragment fragment = ScannerFragment.newInstance();

FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

---

You may also want to take a look at the [sample code](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zxing-sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/sample/FullScannerFragment.java) provided in the repository. The `Fragment` in this sample is set up differently, the view is created within the class, instead of in XML. But it may help you utilize any other features provided by `ZXingScannerView`, as well as handle layout changes.